# Torus action and multigrading.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and $T$ the maximal torus. Suppose that $T$ acts on $G$. Do we have a multigrading on $\mathbb{C}[G]$? How to define the multigrading corresponding to the $T$-action? Thank you very much.

Edit: $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is the coordinate ring of $G$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb C[G]$? Is it the coordinate ring or the group ring?

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer, it is the coordinate ring.

Comment: See this [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104756/action-of-k-on-a-variety-induces-grading) answer. It answers positively in the case of a one-dimensional torus. It seems that the proof can be modified to deal with a higher-dimensional torus as well.

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ acts on $G$. Then we have an action $T \times G \to G$. This gives a coation $\varphi: \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}[T] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G]$. An element $f \in \mathbb{C}[G]$ is called homogeneous of degree $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}[T]$ if $\varphi(f) = \lambda \otimes f$. Therefore there is a multigrading on $\mathbb{C}[G]$ corresponding to the $T$-action.